# Appearance of default header

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R.For example like this -

```
              A   B  C 
           a  1   4  2
           b  2   3  3
           c  4   4  9
```

I transposed that simply using following command-

```
            > new <- t(old)
```

but then I get tranposed dataframe with default header(v1,v2..) that I dont want :

```
              v1 v2 v3
            x a  b  c
            A 1  2  4
            B 4  3  4
            C 2  3  9
```

How to get rid of that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I presume you wrote `new` to a file?  What code did you use for that?

Comment: Are a,b,c and A,B,C your row and column names or part of the data?

Comment: @jessy Could you use `dput` to show the output of `old` example data?